# How to solve a specific circuit with dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, modeling

I am trying to solve this circuit:

[image: V1 is the positive side of Vonc and V2 is the positive side of Vint]

V1 is the positive side of Vonc and V2 is the positive side of Vint

My advisor has us modeling this circuit with respects to some biomedical applications. The dependent sources are actually dependent on things that are static in our test case. Since Vonc and Vint aren't referenced to ground. I also need the current through Rint. V1 and V2 are also needed for this, but I'm not exactly sure how to solve it with all these sources.

This is my advisor's equation:

V1 = Vpre*(Rpre + Rint + Rpost)/Rpre + (V1_initial + Vonc - Vint) * (Rpre + Rint + Rpost)/Rint + Ppost * (Rpre + Rint + Rpost)/Rpost

However, I don't really know if this is correct because of his multiplication of the whole circuit by those 3 resistors. If this is correct, could someone explain it to me? Thanks!

Comment: This is what spice is for...

Comment: Are the negative sides of Vpost and Vpre supposed to be connected to ground? If not, they are not really adding any information to the system. A voltage source does not need to be connected to ground, it just means that it will try to set the positive terminal V volts above the negative terminal (where V is the value of the voltage source). This diagram seems a bit trivial, unless voltage sources are real and not ideal.

Comment: @pscheidler They could be modeled as connected to ground. In the simulation the values will be changed, but yes, they could be described here as connected to ground.